# How can I keep an item of a LazyColumn in view when resizing?

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

I have a `LazyColumn` something along the lines of:

```kotlin
LazyColumn {
    items(list) { item ->
        if (item.isEditing()) {
            TextField(item.text)
        } else {
            Text(item.text)
        }
    }
}
```

See https://github.com/sproctor/ComposeLazyListKeyboardIssue for a working example.

When an item near the end of the visible list of items is set to being edited, the keyboard is displayed, which hides the item and the TextField, which which causes the keyboard to close, which uncovers they TextField, which causes the keyboard to be shown, and so on infinitely.

Is there a way to keep the item with focus in view when the LazyColumn is resized?

Comment: Tried with 1.0.0-beta03, and it works. When the keyboard is shown, the list is resized.

Comment: Yes, the list is resized. Suppose you are displaying 10 elements (indexes 0 - 9), and when it resizes, you are displaying 6 elements (indexes 0 - 5), how do you keep the 10th element in view (indexes 4 - 9)?

Comment: the list scrolls up and the item #9 is shown above the keyboard

Comment: I've created a demo. https://github.com/sproctor/ComposeLazyListKeyboardIssue

It only happens when the activity has android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"

Comment: Thank you for your response. I think it is a bug that only happens under certain conditions that causes the list to not scroll appropriately.

Comment: I also ran into this issue.  I made an `item` at the end of the LazyColumn so at least the user can scroll below the last editText, but I haven't found a better solution.

Comment: I removed the TextField from the rows and used a dialog with a TextField instead.

Comment: Like @Sean already mentioned, it's a bug in the `compose` library when the screen is resized (`windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`). Please find the issue tracker page  [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195330768)

Answer (score 0):

Check this comment
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/195049010#comment15

try again with compose foundation 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT

Comment: Answers that rely on information provided through links are less helpful for future users as the links may break at any point, you should consider including a block quote with relevant snippets from the link and include the link as a source.